# expressing a discrete distribution as a mixture of bernoullis

Tags: probability, self-study

How would one express a discrete distribution as a probabilistic mixture of Bernoulli random variables? An example of a discrete distribution being something like this: $P(X=1)=0.15$, $P(X=2)=0.45$, $P(X=3)=0.40$,

I thought it would be a categorical distribution similar to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) but I was told that is wrong by a professor of mine.

Comment: Think about it in coding terms: "Given a subroutine for drawing from a Bernoulli distribution, how would you draw a sample from a discrete distribution?"

Comment: By definition, a Bernoulli variable can attain only the values $0$ and $1$. Therefore any mixture of Bernoullis can attain only those two values. In order to make sense of this question, then, it will be necessary to expand what is meant by a "Bernoulli" random variable. I can think of several meaningful extensions of this, depending on whether you want to include changes of location, of scale, or both. Exactly what definition of "Bernoulli random variable" do you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_1,A_2, \cdots, A_n$ be $n$ events that are a *partition* of the sample
space $\Omega$. Suppose that $P(A_i) = p_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$ where 
$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$.
Let $\mathbf 1_{A_i}$ be the *indicator function* for event $A_i$. Thus, 
the *random variable* $\mathbf 1_{A_i}$ has value $1$ or $0$ according as
the outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ is a member of $A_i$ or of $A_i^c$. Note
that regardless of the outcome that occurred on a trial of the experiment, 
exactly one of the $\mathbf 1_{A_i}$ has value $1$ and all other $A_j$ have
value $0$.

What is the probability mass function (pmf) of the *random variable*
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mathbf 1_{A_i}$?

Comment: This makes good sense, but it seems to me to be the same thing as the "categorical distribution", no?

Comment: Then maybe you should ask your professor for a clearer definition of what he/she means by `probabilistic mixture` of Bernoulli random variables. In general, a _mixture distribution_ is of the the form $f(x) = \sum_i p_i f_i(x)$ where the $f_i$'s are distributions (pdfs, pmfs, etc) and $\sum_i p_i = 1$.